# Обеспечение целостности данных в БД MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Дано: система контроля за товаром. Есть поставки и есть продажи. Необходимо: обеспечить целостность данных.

---

Более подробно: есть таблица sale_products. В ней есть ID товара и ID продажи. Есть таблица products, в ней есть наименование товара. Вопросов несколько, а именно:

> Как правильнее: создать столбец в таблице products и прибавлять/убавлять значение в зависимости от продажи/поставки
>
> Как правильно сделать таблицу поставки? Есть товар, который будет забракован, т.е. необходимо также сделать списание товара.
>
> Нужно ли делать разные таблицы списания товара и поставки товара? Хотел сделать так: таблица одна, в ней есть столбец type, где 1 - поставка, 2 - списание

Всем заранее спасибо за помощь!

Comment: вы знаете про транзакции?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman да, просто думал о том, есть ли альтернативный способ и какой из них лучше

Comment: транзакции как раз и служат для обеспечения целостности. зачем какой-то другой способ?

Comment: С точки зрения реляционной БД в таблице products в принципе не может быть колонки с количеством товара. Количество должно получатся по таблице движения товара (да, проще сделать одну таблицу в которой будет как поступление так и списание товара) как сумма всех операций. Когда встает вопрос производительности - тогда только в products может быть добавлена колонка количества которую могут вести триггера таблицы движения

Comment: @Mike спасибо) об этом и была речь. Скажите, а как скоро вообще может встать вопрос о производительности? 10 тысяч записей? 100?

Comment: @Alexxosipov Ну это зависит скорее от характера нагрузки. Если у вас один запрос на чтение к БД в минуту, то и 100к записей может не быть особой проблемой, а вот когда у вас сотни запросов, то будет гораздо лучше если они будут дешевы даже на небольшой БД. Так что в принципе о кешировании можно задуматься сразу, что бы потом не переделывать. Особенно если есть страницы которые дают списки с количествами. или даже просто списки доступных товаров

Comment: А еще встает вопрос со списанием товара, что бы не списать в минус ... одну запись `for update` проще заблокировать и проще атомарно списать ...